# Difference between N case studies and case series with N patients

Tags: experiment-design, meta-analysis, case-control-study

Is there any reason to treat data from multiple case studies differently from data from a case series that reports data on multiple patients?

Assuming the case-series intervention was the same for all patients, then the difference between the two study types is clear. Indeed, the Cochrane [glossary](https://community.cochrane.org/glossary) defines a case series as

> "A study reporting observations on a series of individuals, usually all
>   receiving the same intervention, with no control group."

However, I've encountered case series where the intervention (e.g. treatment dosage) was not homogeneous but differed between patients. On the other hand, patients' characteristics will inevitably be heterogeneous anyway, so with those caveats, how is a case series with N=10 patients really different from 10 case studies with N=1 patient each?

Do those 10 patients in the case series need to be analysed differently (say, in a meta-analysis) from how you'd analyse 10 patients coming from 10 case studies, just because the former are reported in a paper together (for convenience), but otherwise have little in common?

Answer (score 2):

From an evidence-hierarchical perspective, they are both retrospective observational studies. They are not prospective, nor experimental so there is no expectation for them to be homogeneous with respect to doses, etc. You would expect more homogeneity for the population and intervention of the case series but not across case studies. Meta-analysis is rarely used when aggregating data from case studies/ series.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear, I was refering to case studies/series whereby something is measured pre-&post-intervention, therefore I don't think one could refer to such a study as retrospective/observational. Also, I thought there were meta-analytical methods that enable aggregating results from non-randomised & non-controlled (i.e. case series) studies?!

Comment: Do you mean n-of-1 studies (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3118090/)? Yes, there are techniques to pool, but remember the old saying... garbage in - garbage out. So if the populations, interventions, etc. are different then what would pooling do except provide a false summary effect estimate.